# PhantomJs: How to stop redirecting to another URL and load original URL

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I was trying to load this URL from forbes.com  using `PhantomJs`

`'http://www.forbes.com/sites/prossermarc/2016/10/14/softbanks-new-100b-tech-fund-shows-exactly-how-its-expanding-beyond-telco/#6e5027484acb'`

But this is redirecting to `http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/`  so I am not able to grab the title of the page which I want.

I tried aborting request if the redirecting URL is `http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/` but that completely halts page load and `phantomjs` fails.

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
 if (requestData.url.split('?')[0] === 'http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/') {
     networkRequest.abort();
 }
};
```

Is there anyway I can stop this redirection and load original URL?

Comment: is it a header redirect or a javascript one?

Comment: @pguardiario header redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can stop this redirection and load original URL?

Yes, try to set a different user agent:

```
page.settings.userAgent = "myAppBot"; // or simply 'bot'.
```

Forbes doesn't redirects bots for sure, I guess it shows ads only to common browser user agents.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can stop this redirection and load original URL?

No, because it is done at the server level (header redirect).

But you can either click "Continue to the article" button or wait until forbes.com automatically redirects you to the article after 5 seconds or so.

I'll show how to wait:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";

// This callback is run every time a page is done loading.
// The first time it is the welcome page, the second time it's the target page.    
page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    // Let's get the URL of current page
    var url = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.location.href;
    });

    console.log(url);

    // Is it the welcome page? No
    if(url.indexOf("forbes/welcome") == -1)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render("forbes-article.png");
            var title = page.evaluate(function(){
                return document.querySelector("h1.article-headline").innerText;
            });
            console.log(title);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);
    }
    // Yes it is the welcome page, let's just wait
    else
    {
        console.log("redirected to welcome screen, waiting");
        page.render("forbes-welcome.png");
    }

};

page.open("http://www.forbes.com/sites/prossermarc/2016/10/14/softbanks-new-100b-tech-fund-shows-exactly-how-its-expanding-beyond-telco/#6e5027484acb");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still think there must be clear way as save article app like pocket and Instapaper parse the content of Forbes.com easily. I am not saying they are using phantom but they must be doing some thing similar to what phantom is doing.